# Группировать данные в flow в kotlin по времени

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, flow

Возникла у меня тут задача:

1. Есть поток данных. Довольно плотный: тысячи объектов в секунду.
2. Его нужно писать в БД, но обрабатывать по одному долго.
3. Соответственно, нужно собирать некоторое количество записей за определённый промежуток времени и писать одной транзакцией.

Среди стандартных методов ничего нужного не нашёл.

Сам, пока что, додумался только до такого:

```kotlin
suspend fun <T> Flow<T>.groupByTime(timeout : Duration): Flow<List<T>> = flow<List<T>> {
    while (true) {
        val list = mutableListOf<T>()
        coroutineScope {
            val job = launch(currentCoroutineContext()) {
                collect { list.add(it) }
            }
            job.start()
            delay(timeout)
            job.cancelAndJoin()
        }
        if (list.size > 0) emit(list)
    }
}
```

Если у кого есть решения лучше, предлагайте.

Comment: А, да. Я знаю, что ```while(true)``` - не лучшее решение. Но что-то не смог придумать, как по нормальному.

Answer (score 0):

У вас как минимум 3 ошибки:

1. Постоянно вызывается this.collect, это приведёт к тому, что вы будете получать одни и те же значения.
2. list используется разными корутинами, можно получить состояние гонки
   https://kotlinlang.org/docs/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html#the-problem
3. Ваша функция никогда не закончится из-за `while (true)` без выхода. Спасёт только cancel на корутину, в которой запускается этот while.

Как мне кажется, правильным решением будет использовать [select](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/select-expression.html).

Пример (Использовать на свой страх и риск! Не протестировано, может неправильно работать в особых случаях):

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun <T> Flow<T>.groupByTime(timeout: Long): Flow<List<T>> = flow {
    coroutineScope {
        val list = mutableListOf<T>()
        val values = produce { collect { send(it) } }
        val ticker = produce {
            while (true) {
                delay(timeout)
                send(Unit)
            }
        }

        suspend fun emitList() {
            if (list.isNotEmpty()) {
                val value = list.toList()
                emit(value)
                list.clear()
            }
        }


        whileSelect {
            values.onReceiveCatching { result ->
                result
                    .onSuccess { list += it }
                    .onFailure {
                        it?.let { throw it }
                        ticker.cancel()
                        emitList()
                    }
                    .isSuccess
            }

            ticker.onReceive {
                emitList()
                true
            }
        }
    }
}
```